# What are the different ways to embed Power BI report in Sharepoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, powerbi

I know two ways,

- First one is, using **modern site page** with  **Power BI** webpart.
- The second option is, using **script editor** webpart with iframe code generated in Power BI tool

In the first option, I am not able to generate the link for the report from the Power BI tool, because the option **Embed in Sharepoint Online** option is missing in Power BI tool. The reason is, we need a pro version of Power BI.

I used second option. So suggest if we have any other option.

Comment: @Anulraj, What type of limitation are you facing in both of these options ?

Comment: @GopalZadafiya I am not facing any issue/limitation in the above said methods. You can help suggest me if we have any other approach.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is register an app in Azure AD for Power BI Report and then embed the report with JavaScript, check the blog below:

[Display a PowerBI report in a SharePoint webpart](https://nearbaseline.com/2016/10/display-a-powerbi-report-in-a-sharepoint-webpart/)

Comment: Thanks Jerry. But this is same as my second option.